# Calculate number of occurences for each value using $inc and create a new document using arrays

Tags: mongodb

For values in all fields A, B, C, D calculate number of occurences for each value. Example: Variable B, occurences 1:1, 2:1, 3:2. (number 1 occures one time, number 2 occures one time, number 3 occures two times)

Create a new document using arrays in which these counted values will be stored, named frequency_{dataset name}.

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c98e8763145b88271b94e3"), "A" : 0, "B" : 1, "C" : 1, "D" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c98e8763145b88271b94e4"), "A" : 0, "B" : 2, "C" : 2, "D" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c98e8763145b88271b94e5"), "A" : 0, "B" : 3, "C" : 3, "D" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c98e8763145b88271b94e6"), "A" : 0, "B" : 3, "C" : 4, "D" : 4 }
```

[image]

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking here. Are you trying to create new documents for each of the "keys" here and have their totals set by the combined results of the values for that "key"? Are you just looking for an output of those totals? You should show what you expect as output based on the above.

Comment: I need an output for column A value:number of times it shows, example, "1:4" (number one: four times), for each of the values.

Comment: Edit your question and show the desired output. You are not explaining it clearly enough.

Comment: Your question rather sounds like a task. What did you do to solve it?

Comment: Well I did not, need a solution so I can understand it